# MongoDB updateMany timeout

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible/necessary to set execution timeout to `DBQuery.Option.noTimeout` for `update` queries? I have a large dataset and a query that may take more than 10 hours to modify all the records. Documentation says that such timeout could only be specified for a cursor via `cursor.addOption()`, but I was unable to find a way to specify a timeout for `write` queries. Does it mean that it is infinite by default? Is there another way to specify a timeout for write operators? Or there is no need to do it at all?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit connection options:

- connectTimeoutMS
- socketTimeoutMS

By default they are both set to never timeout